# T ㅏ (A → B) ∨ (B → A). Give a formal proof of the following theorem.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, formal-proofs

-((A → B) ∨ (B → A)) :AS
A-> B :AS
(A → B) ∨ (B → A) :/I2
*|* :-E1,3
-(A->B) :X4
B :AS
-A :AS
A :AS
(A → B) ∨ (B → A) :/I
This is what I have so far, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: The site is MathJax enabled. please [visit this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) to format your question well.

Comment: What rules ? Use $A \lor \lnot A$.